# What does this TypeScript interface syntax mean?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

I am working with Epics with the Redux library in Angular 4. I have been digging into the `index.d.ts` for this library, and have come across the following:

```
export declare interface Epic<T, S> {
  (action$: ActionsObservable<T>, store: MiddlewareAPI<S>): Observable<T>;
}
```

What does this syntax mean? Since the member has no name, I can only guess that the whole interface defines a function type that takes two parameters — an `ActionsObservable<T>` and a `MiddlewareAPI<S>` — and returns an `Observable<T>`.

Is that right? In which case, why is it defined as an interface?

I am using this interface quite happily following a template from another developer, but I'm curious as to what it means. An extract of its usage looks like this:

```
getStuff(): Epic<IAction, IAppState> {
  return (action$, store): any => action$
    .ofType(actions.SOME_ACTION)
    .mergeMap((_) => {
      return this.apiService.get(`some/api/call/`)
        .map((result) => {
          return actions.someActionSuccess({data: result});
        });
    });
}
```

This kinda supports my understanding, since `getStuff()` is indeed returning a function that has this signature. But something more solid than a wild guess would be great!

Comment: yep that's right, and is defined as an interface so you can give it a type and get typesafety, same as with any other kind of typing.

Comment: is there anything unclear in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44703129/2545680)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that right? In which case, why is it defined as an interface?

Yes, that's correct. It's an interface for the function type `Epic`. You can read more about them [in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types).

It's useful to validate that the callback implements certain signature:

```
interface MyCB {
  (a: string, b: string): string;
}

// expect a callback of type MyCB that returns a string
function forEach(cb: MyCB) {

}

// TS reports an error since the callback doesn't return a string
forEach(() => {});
```